# Cannot open .pdf file with Drive on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///" + "/storage/emulated/0/sample.pdf"), "application/pdf");
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

If you choose Drive it wont open, it will just open intent and close immediately, but if you choose any other app like Word or Dropbox, it will work. Please help?

[Image that asks which app to open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFQbn.png)

Comment: It should not work for any app. Use a file provider and FileProvider.getUriFromFile() to constuct an uri.